# sum of series is also analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$, and  $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$, $f(0)=0$. prove that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(z^n)$$
 converges, and  is also analytic on $D$

Comment: So your book is definitely full of funny questions!

Comment: this   from  textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Rewrote answer.

We'll use a slight modification of Schwarz's lemma. Pick $r<1$ and consider the restriction of $f$ to $B=\overline{B(0,r)}$. Then $f$ has a maximum modulus on this compact set which we call $M$. Going through the motions of the proof of the Schwarz's lemma for any $z \in B$ we can still get a bound of

$$|f(z)| \leq Mr|z|,$$

so let $C=Mr$. Now for any $z \in B(0,r)$ we have

$$\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(z^n)\right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(z^n)| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty C|z|^n \leq \frac{C}{1-|z|}.$$

This gives us convergence on compact subsets as desired.

Comment: Thanks! The textbook give hint: use Schwarz lemma

Comment: Schwarz's lemma is probably easier, let me edit.

Comment: $$f(z)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mz^m$$, so $$f(z^n)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mz^{mn}$$. then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(z^n)=$

Comment: How to get that $|f(z^n)|\leq |z|^n$? It seems that  $f(z)$ is not bounded

Comment: It's the other way around. But notice that $f$ satisifies the hypothesis of Schwarz's lemma so $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ in particular $|f(z^n)|\leq |z^n|=|z|^n$.

Comment: the hypothesis of Schwarz's lemma : $|f(z)| \leq 1$,

Comment: @ziangchen Okay, I rewrote some things.